# Is it possible to obtain normal magic/mundane plate armor in order to accommodate wings in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, armor, dnd-adventurers-league

The sorcerer draconic bloodline allows one to sprout a pair of wings. However, this only works with armor made appropriately to accommodate the wings:

> You can't manifest your wings while wearing armor unless the armor is made to accommodate them

Is it possible to obtain plate armor made specifically to accommodate wings in this way when playing in Adventurers League?

Comment: @T.J.L.: Oh, I know. And OP already answered the question (they're planning to start as a paladin, I think?), though for some reason their reply was deleted (maybe by them?) but mine wasn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you'd need to do anything special to have plate that accommodates your wings. Here's my reasoning:

In *reality*, you don't just buy a set of plate (or most armor) off the rack; It has to be crafted to fit you. My assumption as a DM and player in D&D has always been that when I go to the blacksmith to buy my plate I'm putting in an order with my specifications and getting back what I asked for. Following this line of thinking, it's safe to assume that you can simply specify your armor is designed to accommodate your wings at time of purchase.

Additionally, there's even note in the Armor section of the PHB under **[VARIANT: EQUIPMENT SIZES](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/equipment#GettingIntoandOutofArmor)** regarding this line of thought:

> In most campaigns, you can use or wear any equipment that you find on your adventures, within the bounds of common sense. For example, a burly half-orc won’t fit in a halfling’s leather armor, and a gnome would be swallowed up in a cloud giant’s elegant robe.
>
> The DM can impose more realism. For example, a suit of plate armor made for one human might not fit another one without significant alterations, and a guard’s uniform might be visibly ill-fitting when an adventurer tries to wear it as a disguise.
>
> Using this variant, when adventurers find armor, clothing, and similar items that are made to be worn, they might need to visit an armorsmith, tailor, leatherworker, or similar expert to make the item wearable. The cost for such work varies from 10 to 40 percent of the market price of the item. The DM can either roll 1d4 x 10 or determine the increase in cost based on the extent of the alterations required.

I wanted to be sure I wasn't out of my mind so I checked with the league admins and they said that, unless there's something in the item's description that would prohibit it from accommodating wings, my logic holds true:

[I asked](https://twitter.com/gksmithlcw/status/1106215022911516672) Alan Patrick, Resource Manager for [Adventurers League](http://dndadventurersleague.org/contact-us/campaign-staff/) and Greg Marks, Content Manager for Adventurers League

> **@gksmithlcw**: is there anything in AL that precludes someone who purchases plate from stating at time of purchase that it will accommodate wings (for, say, a winged dragon sorc)? Thanks in advance!
>
> **@warfteiner [Alan Patrick]**: Not unless there's verbiage about that in the item's description (PHB/source for mundane items, DMG/adventure for magic).
>
> **@skerrit7h3green [Greg Marks]**: no

So, there you have it. Just state that it accommodates your wings when you purchase it and you're good to go.

Comment: I've added information on Alan to the post.

Comment: They do count, yes, but I took your advice and cited the armor rules as well. :-)

Answer (score -2):

## It is obtainable, though you will need to spend lots of downtime crafting the item

AL Player's Guide states you can participate in downtime activities when appropriate during or between sessions:

> Downtime and Lifestyle
>
> Your character can participate in the downtime activities before, during, or after a session. You can use the downtime activities found in the Player’s Handbook as well as those that follow; other activities are allowed if outlined in other campaign documents:
>
> ([Adventurer's League Player's Guide v8.2, pg. 4](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALPGv82.pdf))

As for those relevant activities in the PHB:

> Between adventures, the DM might ask you what your character is doing during his or her downtime. Periods of downtime can vary in duration, but each downtime activity requires a certain number of days to complete before you gain any benefit, and at least 8 hours of each day must be spent on the downtime activity for the day to count. The days do not need to be consecutive. If you have more than the minimum amount of days to spend, you can keep doing the same thing for a longer period of time, or switch to a new downtime activity.
>
> Downtime activities other than the ones presented below are possible. If you want your character to spend his or her downtime performing an activity not covered here, discuss it with your DM.
>
> CRAFTING
>
> You can craft nonmagical objects, including adventuring equipment and works of art, You must be proficient with tools related to the object you are trying to create (typically artisan's tools). You might also need access to special materials or locations necessary to create it, For example, someone proficient with smith's tools needs a forge in order to craft a sword or suit of armor. For every day of downtime you spend crafting, you can craft one or more items with a total market value not exceeding 5 gp, and you must expend raw materials worth half the total market value. If something you want to craft has a market value greater than 5 gp, you make progress every day in 5-gp increments until you reach the market value of the item. For example, a suit of plate armor (market value 1,500 gp) takes 300 days to craft by yourself.
>
> Multiple characters can combine their efforts toward the crafting of a single item, provided that the characters all have proficiency with the requisite tools and are working together in the same place. Each character contributes 5 gp worth of effort for every day spent helping to craft the item. For example, three characters with the prerequisite tool proficiency and the proper facilities can craft a suit of plate armor in 100 days, at a total cost of 750 gp.
>
> (Player's Handbook, pg 187)

### As you can see, this is very time-consuming and/or costly for plate.

You can mitigate the time and cost with help from others. If you do not have proficiency with the required tools to craft the armor, you will need to spend downtime training the proficiency first.

> TRAINING
>
> You can spend time between adventures learning a new language or training with a set of tools. Your DM might allow additional training options.
>
> First, you must find an instructor willing to teach you. The DM determines how long it takes, and whether one or more ability checks are required.
>
> The training lasts for 250 days and costs 1 gp per day. After you spend the requisite amount of time and money, you learn the new language or gain proficiency with the new tool.
>
> (Player's Handbook, pg. 187)

Comment: The first line is a problem - in organized play, an individual table DM has no special authority before or after a game session, only while play is actually taking place.

Comment: Oops. The intended statement is, "If the DM does not offer it in-session", would that make it clearer?

Comment: No, not really... a DM can't make stuff up either. In effect, the DDAL metarules *are* the DM, not the individual table DMs.

Comment: The rules seemed to imply a degree of leeway, but to err on the side of strict RAW the references to DM rulings have been removed.